# What is the code smell called when API are encapsulated many times

Tags: programming-practices, code-smell

In legacy code bases, some APIs might be encapsulated by different developers with separate classes many times. Example:

```
public void calculate(int baseIncome) {
  revenueCalculator.calculate(baseIncome,company);
}
```

and the `RevenueCalculator` looks like this:

```
public class RevenueCalculator {
  public void calcualte(int baeIncome, String companyName) {
    departmentRevenueCalculator.calculate(baseIncome, companyName, null);      
  }
}
```

then the `DepartmentCalculator` looks like this:

```
  public class DepartCalculator {
  public void calcualte(int baeIncome, String companyName) {
    coreCalculator.calculate(baseIncome, companyName, null);      
  }
}
```

Even worse, the `CoreCalculator`'s `calculate` might yet call its private method to invoke the core implementation.

As a result, esp. in case of a *bug* in the core implementation, a developer are forced to drill down to the core implementation by clicking the relevant method one-by-one many times. This badly affects the development efficiency

**Question:** what is the more official name of this kind of *code smell*?

Comment: What makes you think there is an "official name" for this? There are surely some common ways in english language to name what you described, but I would not call that an official or canonical software engineering term.

Answer (score 3):

To some extent, the answer to the question is "overabstraction" - developers creating layers for the sake of creating layers, rather than because they are needed.

However, that doesn't necessarily seem to be the case in your example:

- `RevenueCalculator.calculate` adds a `company` parameter which isn't present in the API call itself.
- `DepartmentCalculate.calculate` is called with an additional `null` parameter which isn't present in `RevenueCalculator` (although you've missed this out of the definition of the function so your code wouldn't even compile)

Could those layers be combined? That isn't a question we can answer - if they are the only uses then quite probably they should, but if there are different consumers of each layer then they can't and this is a reasonable layer of abstraction for the level of complexity of your program.

> developer are forced to drill down to the core implementation by clicking the relevant method one-by-one many times. This badly affects the development efficiency

Get a better IDE. This should take seconds.

Comment: thanks a lot :) I will learn this term first. But when first hearing about this term "over-abstraction" this sounds more like a design problem rather than code smell, isn't it

Answer (score 1):

You've presented an example of the problem, but what you haven't shown (and which might be very difficult to discern) is whether that deep layering is architecturally necessary or not.

If *every* call to `CoreCalculator` is deeply indirect like this, and there are few or no direct calls, then it might suggest there are unnecessary layers.

On the other hand, if this is an exceptional case in the system as a whole, then there may still be substantial justification for the existence of the various layers.

The example shown could be just an unfortunate consequence of the essential complexity of the system, or a degenerate case of a design that is fairly adequate overall.

**When there is unnecessary layering in this particular fashion, I'm not aware of a specific term which describes the problem, other than ad-hoc descriptions like "unnecessary layering".**

---

As a final (and ultimately long...) aside, computer scientists have long recognised the idea that "every problem can be solved with more indirection, except the problem of too much indirection".

I think that this belongs to a even more general truth, that every problem can be solved with more things, except the problem of too many things. In other words, more complexity is the solution to every problem, except the problem of human minds having to manage that additional complexity.

Good software design is always about aiming for a design that is as efficient with complexity as possible - for things to be "as simple as possible, but no simpler" (as Einstein put it).

There are virtually unlimited ways in which designs can deviate from these principles, and establishing whether software is reasonably simple requires consideration not only of all the details of the whole edifice of computer automation, but also the detail of the business to which that automation is applied.

Without that massive amount of detail, and without knowledge of both sides of the equation (software and business), advice and judgment is often reduced to platitudes and generalities that the listener cannot correctly apply.

Layering that is unnecessary is obviously a bad thing. But actually deciding whether the layering is reasonably necessary or not, and setting up written examples which distinguish real-world designs with necessary and unnecessary layering, is quite difficult.

Comment: Explanation makes sense, but could you give any reference link about unnecessary layering?

Comment: @Rui, as I say, it's just a term I've come with here on the spot. Not every code defect has a canonical name, a specific and exclusive form, or a criteria which can be stated and then applied mechanically.

Answer (score 1):

The term "Lasagna Code" is sometimes used to refer to this (e.g. as referenced on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code#Lasagna_code)). This term is play on words of the more well-known term "Spaghetti Code". This term definitely isn't well-known enough to be considered official in any way, but it's probably suitable for casual conversation.

Comment: thanks a lot. When Comparing all others' explanations with yours the lesagna code seems to be the correct term

Comment: @Rui, I have to say I'm concerned about this answer. The top result when searching for "lasagna code" actually suggests it is a desirable form of code (unlike the Wiki entry). You were looking for a term that described an undesirable quality in your code. Certainly, this is not a term commonly used or understood by professionals. https://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/pasta.code.html

Comment: @Steve: Maybe not bad code. But I didn't think of it as desirable. Well structured, but monolithic.